# How to disable CustomChromeTab hidding Top bar and secondary tool bar when scrolling down?

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs

Is it possible to **disable** the **hiding url bar and secondary tool bar** feature of CustomChromeTab in **Android** when scrolling down the page?

I added a secondary tool bar at the bottom of chrome by using CustomChromeTab in Android. I want to keep the bottom bar visiable. However, the chrome has enabled the url bar and secondary bar to hide as the user scrolls down on the page by default.

Reference:

I reviewed the source code and find a function called 'enableUrlBarHiding', which actually enable the hiding, so I think another function that do 'mIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_ENABLE_URLBAR_HIDING, false);' should work. But I can not edit the source code and there is no API exposed to do this.

`/**
         * Enables the url bar to hide as the user scrolls down on the page.
         */
        public Builder enableUrlBarHiding() {
            mIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_ENABLE_URLBAR_HIDING, true);
            return this;
        }`

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/custom-tabs-client/blob/master/customtabs/src/android/support/customtabs/CustomTabsIntent.java

Answer (score 3):

putExtra() can be done from CustomTabsIntent, and it works:

 `customTabsIntent.intent.putExtra(CustomTabsIntent.EXTRA_ENABLE_URLBAR_HIDING, false);`

Answer (score 0):

I find a possible way to disable the hiding of secondary tool bar by using

#### CustomTabsIntent.Builder.addToolbarItem(int, Bitmap, String, PendingIntent)

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/custom-tabs-client/blob/master/customtabs/src/android/support/customtabs/CustomTabsIntent.java#L371

However, compared with another init method, the drawback is that it only take Bitmap, which is not as flexible as Remoteviews.

#### CustomTabsIntent.Builder.setSecondaryToolbarViews(@NonNull RemoteViews remoteViews, @Nullable int[] clickableIDs, @Nullable PendingIntent pendingIntent)

Comment: customTabsIntent.intent.putExtra(CustomTabsIntent.EXTRA_ENABLE_URLBAR_HIDING, false);